# Parsing string input C#

Tags: c#, parsing, formatting

Let's say I have a string that is bound to console input and must contain date data in any of the following formats:

```
"dd/mm/yyyy"
"dd.mm.yyyy"
"dd,mm,yyyy"
```

What is the safest way to parse this string into `DateTime` object? Should I use `Regex` approach or simply iterate through `String.Format()` method with all possible upper mentioned input formats till it succeeds in parsing?

Comment: Do you know what cultures correspond to these values? If you do, you can pass them to any parsing function

Comment: It isn't actually based on cultural context, I have to parse real user input and different people tend to type date differently even though they have read the manual and know the format the software expects. I just don't want to throw an exception and make them type the date again but rather parse it regardless of those differences

Comment: You may want to add `-` then. I see from Wikipedia that it's used as a separator in Germany, France

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to use DateTime.ParseExact or DateTime.TryParseExact. The `/` is a special formatting character, the date separator character. In a format string it will be replaced with whatever the date separator is for the application's current culture. It can't be escaped because it is *not* a special character like `\`. This will cause problems if your system's culture uses `.` (Russia and other countries).

To specify a different date separator you need to create a CultureInfo object with the separator you want. The following function accepts a list of separators and tries to parse dates using each separator until one of them succeeds:

```
public static bool TryParseDate(string input, string[] separators, out DateTime date)
{
    var ci = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();

    foreach (var separator in separators)
    {
        ci.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = separator;
        DateTime result;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy", ci, DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                   out date))
            return true;
    }
    date=new DateTime();
    return false;
}
```

There's no need to define multiple formats because `dd/MM/yyyy` matches all cases.

This allows you to write code like the following snippet:

```
var separators = new []{"/",".",",","-"};
DateTime result;
var success1 = TryParseDate("12.05.2015", separators, out result);
var success2 = TryParseDate("12/05/2015", separators, out result);
var success3 = TryParseDate("12,05,2015", separators, out result);
var success4 = TryParseDate("12-05-2015", separators, out result);
```

I added `-` because I see it's a common separator in Germany. You can make the function even more generic by passing the format as another parameter.

`TryParseExact` accepts multiple format parameters. If it weren't for the `/` separator, you could write a single call with all formats:

```
var formats=new []{"dd.MM.yyyy","dd,MM,yyyy","dd-MM-yyyy"};
DateTime result;
var success=DateTime.TryParseExact(input, formats, 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out date)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) do have an overload that you can supply multiple format to it

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified array of formats,
>   culture-specific format information, and style. The format of the
>   string representation must match at least one of the specified formats
>   exactly or an exception is thrown.

Pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to IFormatProvider should handle the separator correctly for `.` `,` `/`

```
var dateformats = new[] { "dd/mm/yyyy", "dd.mm.yyyy", "dd,mm,yyyy" };

DateTime.ParseExact("23/04/2015", dateformats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
DateTime.ParseExact("23.04.2015", dateformats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
DateTime.ParseExact("23,04,2015", dateformats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: `DateTime.TryParseExact` is a better option in this case as it doesn't throw if it fails. The real problem is that there is only *one* format but the date separator changes. The OP will have to pass a custom CultureInfo for each try

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right but OP mentioned `.. must contain date data in any of the following formats`, then `TryParseExact()` added nothing to this case.

Comment: On the contrary. You can check each different format (actually, separator) to see which returns true. It's not only safer but much faster than catching exceptions for each failed format

Comment: First, this edit will throw at least one exception. Second, the first line will *fail* if the user's culture uses a separator other than `/`. `/` is a special character, replaced by the current culture's date separator

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just curious, what actually the use of `IFormatProvider` if it still fail when `InvariantCulture` supplied?

Comment: Didn't see this, the lines is so long that the class is out of the window. You should shorten it, eg `DateTime.ParseExact("12,05,2015",formats,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. You don't need to specify the style, it's None by default

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sure, but there is no such overload for `ParseExact`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `DateTime.TryParseExact` as there are multiple formats it wont generate any exceptions

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent. The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly. The method returns a value that
>   indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

Comment: This deals with the issue in the safest way as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes @astralmaster as  as it doesn't throw any exception if it fails.

Comment: Not quite. `/` is the date separator symbol, replaced by the *actual* separator from the user's culture. Parsing of `dd/mm/yyyy` will fail if that separator is `.` or `,`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes that's why the OP need the `TryParseExact` as exception will not be thrown

Comment: @TusharGupta Although the Idea is for the solution to be able to parse the input regardless of user's culture

Comment: @TusharGupta you misunderstand. TryParseExact will *also* fail in this case and return false. If the OP's culture uses `.`, the string `dd/mm/yyyy` will match *only* `14.05.2015` not `14/05/2015`

Comment: @astralmaster Then you can check each different format before parsing because the separators will cause the parsing errors

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.ParseExact` Method

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent.

Or

`DateTime.TryParseExact` Method

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to
>   its DateTime equivalent. The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly. The method returns a value that
>   indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

**Note :**

> Parse takes regional settings (culture of current thread) into
>   account. Therefore, you need to specify the correct format explicitly
>   with an invariant culture eg. en-US

Answer (score -1):

I reckon just iterate through String.Format, it is probably easier than using a regex. But if you have actual users inputing into wherever you got the DateTimes, a regex is safer, but it should still be surrounded by a try to make it crash-proof.